# Timeout when issuing too many AFNetworking requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I have this code to download 40 json

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in general_URL) {

        NSURL *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];
        NSString *key = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            [self.all_data setObject:[self parseJSONfile:responseObject] forKey:key];

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [mutableOperations addObject:operation];
    }

    NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"progress:%f", (float)numberOfFinishedOperations / totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

        NSLog (@"all done");

    }];
    [manager.operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

As you can see I use a manager to have a queue of request. The problem is that suddenly, it go in timeout with -1001 code.
It happens only in EDGE mode, in wifi and 3g it don't happen.

What's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like the connection is too slow and the server throws a timeout error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of the operation queue, that will control how many concurrent operations are attempted, thus mitigating any timeouts resulting from the fact that iOS limits how many simultaneous network connections are permitted:

```
manager.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
[manager.operationQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

In the absence of this, when you submit your 40 operations, all of them are likely to attempt to start `NSURLConnection` objects, even though only 4 or 5 can really run at at a time. On slow connections, this can result in some of your latter requests timing out.

If you specify the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, it won't attempt to start the latter connections until the prior connections have completed. You'll still enjoy the performance benefit of concurrent requests, but you won't be making a bunch of requests that will timeout because of the throttling of concurrent `NSURLConnection` requests that iOS enforces.